# Using a different service contract for DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dotnetopenauth, datacontract

Recently the company I work for has decided to use DotNetOpenAuth to authorize users who want to make use of a certain webservice I've been developing.

Now, I have a SOAP webservice up and running, and I also have the OAuthConsumer and OAuthServiceProvider samples from DotNetOpenAuth running. The webservice, consumer and service provider all run on IIS7, each in their own site.

My question is, how can I call a method from my webservice's datacontract, rather than a method from DotNetOpenAuth's IDataApi datacontract?

Would I need to build a new version of the DataApi class? In that case, what should this new class extend to (rather than IDataApi)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDataApi` is simply the `[ServiceContract]` in the sample.  You should use the interface that describes your service instead.  Is this SOAP service based on WCF?  If so, simply use your interface.

If you're *not* using WCF then the framework you're using will determine how to hook into its authorization system, and perhaps make your implementation radically different from the sample's.  But using DotNetOpenAuth with it should still work.

Comment: Thank you, that got me thinking in the right direction, but unfortunately I'm not quite there yet. The service is indeed a SOAP service based on WCF, running on IIS7. The service and service provider are running on port 810, and the consumer is also on IIS 7 but running on port 811.  When debuggin the code locally I receive the following error: 
'The message could not be processed because the action 'http://websrv.hszuyd.nl:810/ITimeTableWebService/getTimeTable' is invalid or unrecognized.'  Is there any way to verify that the right action is being used? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Do you get this error before applying OAuth authorization?  If you haven't tried, start there.  Get your WCF service and consumer working great, then apply OAuth authorization to it so you have a basis to work from.

Comment: Ah, that helped. It still isn't fully working, but the original problem is solved. Thank you!